# Node.js: How to prevent calling an async function at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got a pub sub subscriber that calls an async function to update some elastic search indices, but because the subscriber is getting multiple requests very quickly, I get version conflicts from elasticsearch.

I tried adding a processing flag, and checking the flag on an interval to only allow the function to run one at a time.

```
let unitsBeingProcessed = {};
let maxAttempts = 5;

Pubsub.on("unit_upsert", async(message) => {
try {
    let unitId = message.data.unitId;
    console.log(unitId + ' being processed is', unitsBeingProcessed[unitId]);

    // seems like sometimes 2 requests end up in this block at the same time which shouldn't be possible I think..
    if(!unitsBeingProcessed[unitId]){
        unitsBeingProcessed[unitId] = true;
        await elastic.addUnitToCalendar(message.data);
        delete unitsBeingProcessed[unitId];
        message.ack();
    }
    else if(unitsBeingProcessed[unitId]){
        let attempts = maxAttempts;
        // if unit is being processed already, check every 2 seconds to see if it's done yet
        let flagCheck = setInterval(async () => {
            attempts--;
            if(!unitsBeingProcessed[unitId]){
                clearInterval(flagCheck);
                unitsBeingProcessed[unitId] = true;
                await elastic.addUnitToCalendar(message.data);
                delete unitsBeingProcessed[unitId];
                message.ack();
            }
            else {
                if(attempts <= 0){
                    clearInterval(flagCheck);
                    throw new Error('max tries to process unit exceeded');
                }
                console.log(unitId + ' is already being processed. Waiting 2s');
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
} catch(err){
    if(unitsBeingProcessed[message.data.unitId]){
        delete unitsBeingProcessed[message.data.unitId];
    }
    Logger.error({err}, "Error in unit_availability_upsert_index");
}
})
```

I expected elastic.addUnitToCalendar() to not be run if it's already been called and hasn't finished. Most of the time, the interval check works, but occasionally it still calls the function before it's done.

My logs showed unitsBeingProcessed[unitId] is undefined two times in a row. I expected it to print undefined once, and then true the 2nd time, so it would wait. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common multi-threading issue. Normally you would use something called a Mutex. A mutex is like a lock that makes sure that only one person can have the lock at a given time. There isn't one in node.js by default but it looks like some people have wrote some https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex. Give that a try instead of the interval flag, it should make things easier and solve your problem.